# MySQL chained select

Tags: mysql

I have a table `family`

```
+----------------------------+
| id | name   | age | parent |
|----------------------------|
| 1  | Father | 60  | NULL   |
|----------------------------|
| .. | ...... | ..  | .....  |
| N  | Luke   | 20  | N      |
+----------------------------+
```

The column `parent` is a reference to `family - id`. Starting of with the father, how can I select his last descendant using a single select query?

The long way would be to `n = SELECT * FROM family WHERE parent = 1` and then `o = SELECT * FROM family WHERE parent = n`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a recursive query  like this :

```
select @pv:=id from family
join
(select @pv:=1)tmp
where parent=@pv
```

To get the last descendant just use the MAX aggregate function

```
SELECT MAX(@pv:=id) FROM family
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=1)tmp
WHERE parent=@pv
```

UPDATE : 
    For the other way around. To get the ancestor please test this query

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN parent IS NULL 
       THEN ID 
       ELSE @pv:=parent END) Ancestor
FROM family
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=3)tmp
WHERE (CASE WHEN parent IS NULL OR id=@pv 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: That looks like the one thanks, I'll do more testing and mark it as the right answer once tested. (I didn't down vote btw :v)

Comment: @LukeMadhanga that is OK i made a mistake due to hurrying

Comment: Thanks that looks like the one. Can I ask, if I had the last descent, how can I get the first ancestor?